# Angular v2.0.0 vs v5.1.2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

Does Angular 2 differ a lot, in terms of syntax, from angular 5?

I'm asking because I got on Christmas pretty new book (published at the end of November) about Angular 2 and when I wanted to install required packages via npm, it automatically installed version 5.1.2 of angular, when the book is basing on version 2.0.0.

I wonder if I will be able to normally carry out the examples from the book, or maybe should I downgrade to version 2.0.0?

Actually I don't know if it's a topic for this forum, but I would be very if anybody could answer me.

```
{
  "name": "angular-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Template for angular app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.2",

    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.19",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18",

    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't like AngularJs (1) vs Angular(2).   Mostly keeping up with Typescript latest updates. Optimization in build process in the background. The most recent change has been moving away from an Http Module to HttpClient Module which was meant to be implemented to ease the HTTP requests feature. I'd stick to the latest Angular if you're familiar with Angular 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular team keep enhancing angular more and more. its started with angular 2.0.0 and today the latest stable release is 7.0.0 (2018-10-18).

So if you want to know each change that is added after each version, you can look at this change log file link:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

This way you can for example know what is removed and what feature is added in each version.

You can keep use your book, its probably a good source to learn with, but you can search in that change log file for example to see if a feature is removed or not and use the new one.

So angular 5 (5.1.2 here) is better than angular 2 because it has added many new features and many fixes that angular 2 or 4. and still under development to bring better API and bug fixes and optimizations every new release.